# c# Set and Reset Color from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hey Guys i use the DataGridViewCell.Style property to set the Background color for each Cell i clicked on it.

```
if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataMenu.NewRowIndex)
{
    return;
}
var dataGridViewCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle(dataMenu.DefaultCellStyle)
{
    BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
};
dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style = dataGridViewCellStyle;
```

**This looks exactly like this:**
[image]

But now i want that if i click on a other Cell in the same Column, that the whole Column change the Background Color to White before it set the next Cell to 'Color.CornflowerBlue'

I want to avoid that multiple Cells in the same Column can be have the same color.
*For each Column it should only be possible to set the color on one cell!*

**It should not possible to do something like this:**
As you can see in the Column "Montag" it was possible to change the colors for multiple cells.
I want that if i click now on a other Cell in "Montag" then the whole Column should be resetted and set the Color on the new focused Cell.
[image]

i already tried this piece of code:

```
 dataMenu.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

But this change only the BackColor behind the first BackColor Set function i wrote on the Top of this post.

Comment: IMHO you will need to set the style for each individual cell, because the `DefaultCellStyle` will only be used if a cell doesn't have a style explicilty set, hence the name `Default`. So either again explicilty set the cell's style `dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style = someStyle;` or remove the explicit style `dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style = null;` by setting it to `null` the `DefaultCellStyle` should again take effect.

Comment: However, this only has an effect on the currently selected cell, but I would like to reset the entire column.

Comment: I meant to simply `for loop` the cells of the column. `for (int i = 0; i < dataMenu.Rows.Count; i++) dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, i] = someStyle;`

Comment: Same Result. seems not to work for me. I need a method to overwrite the setted Color for the whole Column. not only for a single Cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you set the style of a cell, clear the style of other cells on the same column. All it takes is a little modification of your initial code

```
private void DataMenu_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataMenu.NewRowIndex)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dataMenu.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var cell = dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, i];
        if (cell.HasStyle)
        {
            cell.Style = null;
        }
    }
    var style = new DataGridViewCellStyle(dataMenu.DefaultCellStyle)
    {
        BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
    };
    dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style = style;
}
```

---

I noticed some side-effects while reproducing your issue. Decided to give additional recommendations, just in case

Set `SelectionBackColor` and `SelectionForeColor` of default cell style same as that of unselected state.

```
dataMenu.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataMenu.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
dataMenu.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = dataMenu.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
```

You can do it in Designer as well. Select your data grid view in designer. In property grid modify `DefaulCellStyle` property.

Do the same thing when you set `Style` of a cell in code.

```
style.SelectionBackColor = style.BackColor;
style.SelectionForeColor = style.ForeColor;
dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style = style;
```

If you need deselect already selected cell then you can use following code. It deselectes if selected cell is clicked.

```
private void DataMenu_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataMenu.NewRowIndex)
    {
        return;
    }
    var cell = dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (cell.HasStyle)
    {
        cell.Style = null;
    }
    else
    {
        var style = new DataGridViewCellStyle(dataMenu.DefaultCellStyle)
        {
            BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
        };
        style.SelectionBackColor = style.BackColor;
        style.SelectionForeColor = style.ForeColor;
        cell.Style = style;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataMenu.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (i != e.RowIndex)
            {
                dataMenu[e.ColumnIndex, i].Style = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the second time today you saved me :) thanks